# Scala check a Sequence of Eithers

Tags: scala

I want to update a sequence in Scala, I have this code :

```
def update(userId: Long): Either[String, Int] = {
  Logins.findByUserId(userId) map {
    logins: Login => update(login.id,
      Seq(NamedParameter("random_date", "prefix-" + logins.randomDate)))
  } match {
    case sequence : Seq(Nil, Int) => sequence.foldLeft(Right(_) + Right(_))
    case _ => Left("error.logins.update")
  }
}
```

Where `findByUserId` returns a `Seq[Logins]` and `update` returns `Either[String, Int]` where `Int` is the number of updated rows, 
and `String` would be the description of the error.

What I want to achieve is to return an `String` if while updating the list an error happenes or an `Int` with the total number of updated rows.

The code is not working, I think I should do something different in the `match`, I don't know how I can check if every element in the `Seq` of `Either`s is a `Right` value.

Comment: You seem to have two functions called `update` - the one shown here, and then one that takes two parameters (the first being of whatever the type of `login.id` is, and the second of type `String`).  What does that function returns?  Also, where does `login` come from - the function you're passing to `map` has an input of `logins`, not `login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really use a fold if you want to exit early. A better solution would be to recursively iterate over the list, updating and counting successes, then return the error when you encounter one.

Here's a little example function that shows the technique. You would probably want to modify this to do the update on each login instead of just counting.

```
val noErrors = List[Either[String,Int]](Right(10), Right(12))
val hasError = List[Either[String,Int]](Right(10), Left("oops"), Right(12))

def checkList(l: List[Either[String,Int]], goodCount: Int): Either[String, Int] = {
  l match {
    case Left(err) :: xs =>
      Left(err)
    case Right(_) :: xs =>
      checkList(xs, (goodCount + 1))
    case Nil =>
      Right(goodCount)
  }

}

val r1 = checkList(noErrors, 0)
val r2 = checkList(hasError, 0)

// r1: Either[String,Int] = Right(2)
// r2: Either[String,Int] = Left(oops)
```

Comment: Thank you @justinhj, as you said I modified for my code and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to using Scalaz or Cats you can use `traverse`. An example using Scalaz :

```
import scalaz.std.either._
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

val logins = Seq(1, 2, 3)

val updateRight: Int => Either[String, Int] = Right(_)
val updateLeft:  Int => Either[String, Int] = _ => Left("kaboom")

logins.toList.traverseU(updateLeft).map(_.sum)  // Left(kaboom)
logins.toList.traverseU(updateRight).map(_.sum) // Right(6)
```

Traversing over the logins gives us a `Either[String, List[Int]]`, if we get the sum of the `List` we get the wanted `Either[String, Int]`.

- We use `toList` because there is no [`Traverse`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Traverse) instance for `Seq`.
- `traverse` is a combination of `map` and `sequence`.
- We use `traverseU` instead of `traverse` because it infers some of the types for us (otherwise we should have introduced a type alias or a type lambda).
- Because we imported `scalaz.std.either._` we can use `map` directly without using a right projection (`.right.map`).

Comment: Thank you @PeterNeyens is the most elegant solution, I will try to implement later

Answer (score 1):

You want to stop as soon as an update fails, don't you? 
That means that you want to be doing your matching inside the `map`, not outside. `Try` is actually a more suitable construct for this purpose, than `Either`. Something like this, perhaps:

```
def update(userId: Long): Either[String, Int] = Try {
   Logins.findByUserId(userId) map { login => 
     update(login.id, whatever) match {
       case Right(x) => x
       case Left(s) => throw new Exception(s)
     }
   }.sum
}
.map { n => Right(n) }
.recover { case ex => Left(ex.getMessage) }
```

BTW, a not-too-widely-known fact about scala is that putting a `return` statement inside a lambda, actually returns from the enclosing method. So, another, somewhat shorter  way to write this would be like this:

```
def update(userId: Long): Either[String, Int] = 
   Logins.findByUserId(userId).foldLeft(Right(0)) { (sum,login) => 
     update(login.id, whatever) match {
       case Right(x) => Right(sum.right + x)
       case error@Left(s) => return error
     }
   }
```

Also, why in the world does `findUserById` return a *sequence*???

Comment: thank you for your answer. The findUserById returns a Seq because execute an anorm select.